# UnsatifiedLinkException java -- caused by LTI-CIVIL

Tags: java, webcam, unsatisfiedlinkerror, lti

```
Exception in thread "main" com.lti.civil.CaptureException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no civil in java.library.path
    at com.lti.civil.impl.jni.NativeCaptureSystemFactory.createCaptureSystem(NativeCaptureSystemFactory.java:24)
    at pst.CaptureSystemTest.main(CaptureSystemTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no civil in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.lti.civil.impl.jni.NativeCaptureSystemFactory.createCaptureSystem(NativeCaptureSystemFactory.java:21)
    ... 1 more
```

I am attempting to run `CaptureSystemTest.java` that comes with the lti-civil download. I have added that class to my own package in `Eclipse` and I have added all the jars that came with lti-civil's download.

I looked at a similar question to this on stack and the only answer was to add the following code to the program:

```
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "C:/Work/lti-civil/native/win32-x86/" );
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

However, `Field` is flagged as an error with Eclipse giving 18 suggestions for imports.

My question is:
**How do I start using LTI-CIVIL for application development?**
I mean, what are the things I need to do? Like add jars, etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is LTI-CIVIL but typically 3rd party libraries are packaged into jars and you have to include it in your build classpath. Search for various ways you can add jars to classpath such as [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) tutorial.